# NullpointerException while listing files and directory from sdcard

Tags: android, file, list

I am trying to list all files from sdcard in nexus7,But i am getting nullpointer exception.

**The below code works fine in samsung tab2,but getting issue in nexus7.**

Please help me if anyone have idea.

```
    ArrayList<String> listFolders = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> listFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    String globalPath = "";




     public void onClikButton(View v) {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/";

        getDirectory(path);
    }


    public void getDirectory(String path) {
        //String setPath = path;
        globalPath = path;
        Log.i("getDirectory","globalPath = " + globalPath);

        String[] splitPath = path.split("/");
        int count = splitPath.length;
        Log.i("getDirectory","globalPath count = " + count);
        if(count==3)
        {
            // Root
            btnBack.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            btnBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        File directory = new File(globalPath);
        File[] listDirectory =null;

        if(directory.exists()) {
                  listDirectory = directory.listFiles();
       for(int i=0; i<listDirectory.length;i++)
        {
        File getFolder = listDirectory[i];
        if(getFolder.isDirectory())
        {
            listFolders.add(getFolder.getName());
        }
       }
    }
     }
```

Log:-

```
12-26 15:49:53.390: E/(6322): results[0]: 3839
12-26 15:49:53.390: E/(6322): results[1]: 3839
12-26 15:49:53.390: E/(6322): results[2]: 0
12-26 15:49:53.390: E/(6322): results[3]: 0
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322): Process: com.allappsmobile.pdfsdk.app, PID: 6322
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.allappsmobile.pdfsdk.app/com.allappsmobile.pdfsdk.app.ActivityDirectory}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at com.allappsmobile.pdfsdk.app.ActivityDirectory.getDirectory(ActivityDirectory.java:89)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at com.allappsmobile.pdfsdk.app.ActivityDirectory.onCreate(ActivityDirectory.java:47)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
12-26 15:49:53.590: E/AndroidRuntime(6322):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Where exactly are you getting exception?

Comment: What do you see in log? `Log.i("getDirectory","globalPath = " + globalPath);` what is the path logged?

Comment: did you add the correct permisions..

Comment: I am getting in log  12-26 15:49:53.580: I/getDirectory(6322): globalPath = /storage/emulated/0/.

Comment: @VipulJ, whenever going to listing dir. means in for loop.

Comment: first of all check whether the given path is available or not

Comment: @jagdish Have you checked in your specified path ,whether there is any directory or files available or not ?

Comment: @GrIsHu,i also check by this line if(directory.exists()){ // for loop }. but nullpointer when going to excute loop.

Comment: Where is this line `if(directory.exists()){ // for loop }` in your code ?

Comment: I updated my code in question.

Comment: The above code works fine in samsung tab2,but getting issue in nexus7.

Comment: Try to remove your `if(directory.exists())` condition because the file path which you are trying to check is already exists.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43913/discussion-between-jagdish-and-grishu)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/";
```

with

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your onClickButton() with this

```
public void onClikButton(View v) {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

    getDirectory(path);
}
```

Comment: It is invalid because path is string variable and we assign file type. Please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. replace

   ```
   String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/";
   ```

   with

   ```
   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
   ```
2. replace

   ```
   if(count==3)
   ```

   with

   ```
   if(path.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutPath()))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have find this on stack overflow...may be it helps..

Seems to be a [known issue affecting Android USB file access over MTP](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282). The MTP cache gets out of date until a reboot of the phone.

A workaround is:

1. Clear the "Media Storage" app's data
2. Use the [SDrescan](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1719628) app to force an update.

Or just avoid using USB at all.The issue does not affect other methods of accessing the files. For example, try [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bero.sdrescan&hl=en) to transfer files.

everything is a link to **/storage/emulated/legacy** anyway, which itself is a link to **/mnt/shell/emulated/0** which contains the file

Comment: thanks for reply @nitesh goel. My code work in samsung tab2 but not in nexus7.

Comment: yes this is a issue particular on nexus devices.you can check on SO.